# Serialization/Deserialization of Dictionary<IntPtr,CustomObject> needed in C++/CLI while injecting dll to other process

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, c++-cli, code-injection

I need to serialize an object array `array<object^>^` in C++/CLI which contains one `intPtr` and a dictionary `Dictionary<IntPtr,ObjectInfo>` where `ObjectInfo` is some custom class. It is serializing properly but while deserializing it gives this error:

> ```
> "System.Runtime.Serialization..SerializationException:Unable
> ```
>
> to load type
>   System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary'2[[System.IntPtr,mscorlib,
>   Version=4.0.0.0",
>   Cultural=neutral,PublicKeyToken=..............],[System.Collection.Generic.List'1[[SharedObjects.ObjectInfo,SharedObjects,Version....]]
>   requires deserialization.

I am passing this `array<object^>^` to `Type->InvokeMember` as arguments, and these arguments need to be de-serialized before passing to `InvokeMember`.

But it fails during deserialization.

### Serialize Code:

```
     void Serialize(Object^ obj)
     {
        if (obj == nullptr)
        {
           _length = 0;
           return;
        }

     // We could write directly to shared data through an UnmanagedMemoryStream, and
     // catch an error if not big enough. But then we don' get info about how much memory
     // we needed, so instead we write to a dynamically resizing MemoryStream first.

       MemoryStream^ memstream = gcnew MemoryStream();
       BinaryFormatter^ formatter = gcnew BinaryFormatter();
       formatter->Serialize(memstream, obj);
      _length = (int)memstream->Length;

      if (_length > sizeof(_data))
      {
          throw gcnew ApplicationException(String::Format("Not enough shared memory to transfer data (have {0} bytes, but {1} bytes required)", sizeof(_data), _length));
      }

      UnmanagedMemoryStream^ stream = gcnew UnmanagedMemoryStream(_data, _length, _length, FileAccess::Write);
      memstream->WriteTo(stream);
      memstream->Close();
      stream->Close();
   }
```

### Deserialize Code

```
  Object^ Deserialize()
  {
    if (_length == 0)
    {
       return nullptr;
    }

    UnmanagedMemoryStream^ stream = gcnew UnmanagedMemoryStream(_data, _length, _length, FileAccess::Read);
    BinaryFormatter^ formatter = gcnew BinaryFormatter();
    Object^ obj = formatter->Deserialize(stream);
    stream->Close();
    return obj;
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried your code and it works perfectly with a custom serializable class.

Did you try your code with a simple serializable class to ensure _data value is not corrupt before deserialization?

Is your serialization and deserialization code in same assembly? Maybe you have 2 assemblies referencing different versions of your assembly containing your custom ShareObject.ObjectInfo class.

Here is my test code:

```
using namespace System;
using namespace System::IO;
using namespace System::Collections::Generic;
using namespace System::Runtime::InteropServices;
using namespace System::Runtime::Serialization::Formatters::Binary;

System::Byte* _data;
int _length;

void Serialize(Object^ obj)
{
  MemoryStream^ memstream = gcnew MemoryStream();
  BinaryFormatter^ formatter = gcnew BinaryFormatter();
  formatter->Serialize(memstream, obj);
  _length = (int)memstream->Length;

  UnmanagedMemoryStream^ stream = gcnew UnmanagedMemoryStream(_data, _length, _length, FileAccess::Write);
  memstream->WriteTo(stream);
  memstream->Close();
  stream->Close();
}

Object^ Deserialize()
{
  UnmanagedMemoryStream^ stream = gcnew UnmanagedMemoryStream(_data, _length, _length, FileAccess::Read);
  BinaryFormatter^ formatter = gcnew BinaryFormatter();
  Object^ obj = formatter->Deserialize(stream);
  stream->Close();
  return obj;
}

[SerializableAttribute]
ref class SerializableClass
{
public:
  IntPtr ptr;
  String^ string;
  List<SerializableClass^>^ list;
 };

int main(array<String ^> ^args)
{
  IntPtr ptr = Marshal::AllocHGlobal(1000);
  _data = (System::Byte*)ptr.ToPointer();

  array<SerializableClass^>^ arr = gcnew array<SerializableClass^>(2);
  for (int i = 0; i < arr->Length; i++)
  {
    SerializableClass^ c = gcnew SerializableClass();
    c->ptr = System::IntPtr(1234);
    c->list = gcnew List<SerializableClass^>();

    SerializableClass^ c2 = gcnew SerializableClass();
    c2->string = "Value";
    c->list->Add(c2);
    c->list->Add(c2);

    arr[i] = c;
  }

  Serialize(arr);

  array<SerializableClass^>^ deserializedClass = dynamic_cast<array<SerializableClass^>^>(Deserialize());

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: yeah..
CustomObject is in other class library..but that class is there serializeable...

Comment: And you don't load 2 different version of this class library with different version number? That can explain this kind of issue

Comment: this is shared class library where this custom object is defined which is loaded in both same compiled date & time based version. no different versions. shared copy maintained. One class library referenced by two modules.

Comment: And did you try to serialize another object (like my SerializableClass)?

Comment: I tested your code and it was working fine..:-) amazingly the old one also working fine whenever used within the same code path.

Comment: I tested your code and it was working fine..:-) amazingly the old one 
also working fine whenever used within the same code path.
Actually this one deserialized in some hooked function which is basically the hooked procedure of process main window. This one accessed by its id which I collected from GetWindowThreadProcessId and after sending the message whith SendMessage(hWnd,...) it MessageHookProc that gets called. In that function I am writing deserializing the code there..